# Extract complete text between two variables

Tags: r

I have a dataframe containing 3 columns, 1st col contain chat between two people, 2nd col contain agent_name and 3rd col contain customer name.

Example of 1st col data:

[image]

I have extracted agent name and customer name and assigned it to variables, I want to extract any text that lies between these two variables, there may be multiple spaces or different pattern I want to extract complete text between the variables. For example in attached image I have variable a="armando r" and variable b="jane"

text:

```
armando r armando r: hello im armando how can i help you today jane: hi i had a question about parental leave jane: can you tell me an overview of time we can take off and if we want to extend that time armando r: partner physicians may take up to days of parenting leave you are eligible to begin the leave days prior to your expected due date and then would have days left for bondingparenting leave if you would like to take additional time off then either vacation or leave without pay can be applied jane: got it during the days is that when we apply for disability with the state jane: or how do we get our salary armando r: typically partner physicians are not eligible for sdi benefits but you would be eligible for the compensation continuance program covers of monthly covered earnings prorated to work schedule armando r: there is a day waiting period as well during the first days partners may use accrued sick leave vacation or lwop jane: ok thank you how do we apply for that and when should we apply for the compensation continuance program jane: also do we have to use accrued sick leave vacation lwop during the day waiting period armando r: when is the expected due date jane: end of april armando r: i would recommend contacting the phr shared services department days prior to the expected due date and you can be connected to a leave coordinator jane: ok thank you armando r: your leave coordinator can provide a detailed overview of how the parenting leave program works armando r: is there anything else i can help you with armando r: thank you for your time today good bye
```

Comment: Please do not supply data as an image.  We cannot code to that. Instead, paste the text into your question so that we can cut and paste into code.

Comment: Formatting is often helpful, and long questions can be deterring. I've suggested an edit that puts the text in a [code block](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code), not sure if that's the best but it keeps it compact.

Comment: You mention already having the names extracted, but you don't provide what they are. You also mentioned a dataframe, is that extraneous for this question, or is it important enough that you might want to *give us* the dataframe? If so, `dput(datname)` (or `dat(head(datname))` if large) would be helpful to us.

Comment: name I have mentioned, armando r and jane, dataframe I cant provide as its on a secure network, you can help to extarct from this text I'll apply it on dataframe

Comment: That text contains multiple instances of each name. Please [edit] your question and include your expected output given this sample.

Comment: yes text is going to be like that, multiple instances of names, lets say armando r i assign to var a and jane to var b, i need to extract text that comes in between var a and var b, armando r written text should be extracted separately and same for jane

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the names of the interview partners as pattern input and using lookaround you can do this:

```
library(stringr)
names <- c("armando r", "jane")
str_extract_all(str, 
            paste("(?<=: )[\\w\\s]+(?= ", paste0("\\b(", paste(names, collapse = "|"), ")\\b|$"), ")", sep = ""))
[[1]]
 [1] "hello im armando how can i help you today"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
 [2] "hi i had a question about parental leave"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
 [3] "can you tell me an overview of time we can take off and if we want to extend that time"                                                                                                                                                                                                            
 [4] "partner physicians may take up to days of parenting leave you are eligible to begin the leave days prior to your expected due date and then would have days left for bondingparenting leave if you would like to take additional time off then either vacation or leave without pay can be applied"
 [5] "got it during the days is that when we apply for disability with the state"                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
 [6] "or how do we get our salary"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
 [7] "typically partner physicians are not eligible for sdi benefits but you would be eligible for the compensation continuance program covers of monthly covered earnings prorated to work schedule"                                                                                                    
 [8] "there is a day waiting period as well during the first days partners may use accrued sick leave vacation or lwop"                                                                                                                                                                                  
 [9] "ok thank you how do we apply for that and when should we apply for the compensation continuance program"                                                                                                                                                                                           
[10] "also do we have to use accrued sick leave vacation lwop during the day waiting period"                                                                                                                                                                                                             
[11] "when is the expected due date"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
[12] "end of april"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
[13] "i would recommend contacting the phr shared services department days prior to the expected due date and you can be connected to a leave coordinator"                                                                                                                                               
[14] "ok thank you"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
[15] "your leave coordinator can provide a detailed overview of how the parenting leave program works"                                                                                                                                                                                                   
[16] "is there anything else i can help you with"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
[17] "thank you for your time today good bye"
```

**EDIT**:

if you want to have the utterances by each person separately, you can subset the `names` vector using its indices; e.g., `names[1]` matches `armando r`. Thus, the following extracts `armando r`'s speech:

```
str_extract_all(str, paste0("(?<=", names[1], ":\\s).*?(?=\\s*(?:", paste(names, collapse="|"), "):|$)"))
[[1]]
[1] "hello im armando how can i help you today"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
[2] "partner physicians may take up to days of parenting leave you are eligible to begin the leave days prior to your expected due date and then would have days left for bondingparenting leave if you would like to take additional time off then either vacation or leave without pay can be applied"
[3] "typically partner physicians are not eligible for sdi benefits but you would be eligible for the compensation continuance program covers of monthly covered earnings prorated to work schedule"                                                                                                    
[4] "there is a day waiting period as well during the first days partners may use accrued sick leave vacation or lwop"                                                                                                                                                                                  
[5] "when is the expected due date"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
[6] "i would recommend contacting the phr shared services department days prior to the expected due date and you can be connected to a leave coordinator"                                                                                                                                               
[7] "your leave coordinator can provide a detailed overview of how the parenting leave program works"                                                                                                                                                                                                   
[8] "is there anything else i can help you with"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
[9] "thank you for your time today good bye"
```

Data:

```
str <- "armando r armando r: hello im armando how can i help you today jane: hi i had a question about parental leave jane: can you tell me an overview of time we can take off and if we want to extend that time armando r: partner physicians may take up to days of parenting leave you are eligible to begin the leave days prior to your expected due date and then would have days left for bondingparenting leave if you would like to take additional time off then either vacation or leave without pay can be applied jane: got it during the days is that when we apply for disability with the state jane: or how do we get our salary armando r: typically partner physicians are not eligible for sdi benefits but you would be eligible for the compensation continuance program covers of monthly covered earnings prorated to work schedule armando r: there is a day waiting period as well during the first days partners may use accrued sick leave vacation or lwop jane: ok thank you how do we apply for that and when should we apply for the compensation continuance program jane: also do we have to use accrued sick leave vacation lwop during the day waiting period armando r: when is the expected due date jane: end of april armando r: i would recommend contacting the phr shared services department days prior to the expected due date and you can be connected to a leave coordinator jane: ok thank you armando r: your leave coordinator can provide a detailed overview of how the parenting leave program works armando r: is there anything else i can help you with armando r: thank you for your time today good bye"
```

Comment: I've adjusted the code to what you mentioned in a comment

Comment: ok for one its fine, instead of specific name can we use any variable, when names are dynamic

Comment: Without knowing what they names are I don't think this will be possible; but you said you have a list of the possible names. That list could be used.

Comment: Yeah, I have extracted names in a separate column, but how I can use it, lets say i'm assigning variables a="armando r" and b="jane" and when i do unlist(str_extract_all(f, "(?<=: )[\\w\\s]+(?= (a):)"), it gives nothing

Comment: its not extracting the exact text separately.

Comment: I don't know what you mean: what exactly does not work?

Comment: Extracting speech by individual speaker

Comment: On my end, this works, e.g., for Jane: `jane <- unlist(str_extract_all(str, paste("(?<=: )[\\w\\s]+(?= ", paste0("\\b(", names[2], ")\\b", collapse = "|"), ":)", sep = "")))`. Are you using this exact same code or have you altered it?

Comment: same exact code I tried but not sure why it didnt work, anyhow I have got some workaround for that, thanks for all your help.

Comment: Now, finally, here's the code that works. Try it out and let me know!

Comment: perfect! it did worked, and saved me from using the loops , great thanks

Answer (score 0):

```r
strsplit(txt, paste0("(", paste(a, b, sep = "|"), "):"))
# [[1]]
#  [1] "armando r "                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
#  [2] " hello im armando how can i help you today "                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
#  [3] " hi i had a question about parental leave "                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
#  [4] " can you tell me an overview of time we can take off and if we want to extend that time "                                                                                                                                                                                                            
#  [5] " partner physicians may take up to days of parenting leave you are eligible to begin the leave days prior to your expected due date and then would have days left for bondingparenting leave if you would like to take additional time off then either vacation or leave without pay can be applied "
#  [6] " got it during the days is that when we apply for disability with the state "                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
#  [7] " or how do we get our salary "                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
#  [8] " typically partner physicians are not eligible for sdi benefits but you would be eligible for the compensation continuance program covers of monthly covered earnings prorated to work schedule "                                                                                                    
#  [9] " there is a day waiting period as well during the first days partners may use accrued sick leave vacation or lwop "                                                                                                                                                                                  
# [10] " ok thank you how do we apply for that and when should we apply for the compensation continuance program "                                                                                                                                                                                           
# [11] " also do we have to use accrued sick leave vacation lwop during the day waiting period "                                                                                                                                                                                                             
# [12] " when is the expected due date "                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
# [13] " end of april "                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
# [14] " i would recommend contacting the phr shared services department days prior to the expected due date and you can be connected to a leave coordinator "                                                                                                                                               
# [15] " ok thank you "                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
# [16] " your leave coordinator can provide a detailed overview of how the parenting leave program works "                                                                                                                                                                                                   
# [17] " is there anything else i can help you with "                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
# [18] " thank you for your time today good bye"
```

Comment: how can we separate text here from armando r and jane using variable a and b instead of providing name directly

Answer (score -1):

I have used str_replace_all function to create a pattern, below is the code, its not that much efficient but it did worked

pattern_agent_text="\bABCD\s*(.*?)(?=\s{2}[^:]*[A-Za-z]:|$)"

for (i in 1:nrow(df))

{

txt=df[i,3]

txt=str_replace_all(txt,"\w[a-z]*\s[a-z]{1}:","ABCD:")

txt=str_replace_all(txt,"\w[a-z]{2,15}:","   WXYZ:")

txt1=str_extract_all(txt,pattern_agent_text)

txt2=str_remove_all(txt,pattern_agent_text)

txt1=toString(txt1)

txt2=toString(txt2)

txt1=sub('.',"",txt1)

txt2=sub('.',"",txt2)

txt1=gsub("[[:punct:]]","",txt1)

txt2=gsub("[[:punct:]]","",txt2)

remove_word=c("ABCD","WXYZ","\n")

txt1=gsub(paste(remove_word,collapse='|'),"",txt1)

txt2=gsub(paste(remove_word,collapse='|'),"",txt2)

txt1=gsub("\s+"," ",txt1)

txt2=gsub("\s+"," ",txt2)

df[i,6]=txt1

df[i,7]=txt2

}